# (node:4044) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I sort of need help here, honestly not sure where I went wrong, here is the full code. I am sort of new, just trying to bring back the mention user and the reason back in a message instead of doing anything with this information.

```
const { client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const { prefix } = require("../config.json");




module.exports = {
    name: "report",
    description: "This command allows you to report a user for smurfing.",
    catefory: "misc",
    usage: "To report a player, do $report <discord name> <reason>",
    async execute(message, client){

        function getUserFromMention(mention) {
            if (!mention) return;
        
            if (mention.startsWith('<@') && mention.endsWith('>')) {
                mention = mention.slice(2, -1);
        
                if (mention.startsWith('!')) {
                    mention = mention.slice(1);
                }
        
                return client.users.cache.get(mention);
            }
        }
        

        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

        const offender = getUserFromMention(args[0]);

        if (args.length < 2) {
            return message.reply('Please mention the user you want to report and specify a reason.');
        }
    
        const reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');

        message.reply("You reported",offender,"for reason:", reason)
    }

}
```

If I put no mention, I end up with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VplYT.png)

And If I do put a mention
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97026.png)
I get the above error with no response.

```
(node:4044) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined
```

Index.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.prefix = prefix;
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();


const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args,client));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args,client));
    }
}

client.login(token);
```

Comment: Can you please show the code where you invoke this?

Comment: By invoke, I mean where you put `<something>.execute()`

Comment: Also, to put strings together, you have to use `+`, not `,`. Use this in message.reply: `"You reported " + offender + " for reason: " + reason`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, apologies @MrMythical

Comment: In which comment?

Comment: Alright, gotcha on the string part, thank you will change now @MrMythical

Comment: I mean in your root file, where you require this file, show me the execute() code

Comment: <something>.execute comment

Comment: by root file, you mean client.js, right?

Comment: do you have an index.js?

Comment: yeah, i do, ill provide it above

Comment: Great! That could help

Comment: index.js seems fine. Check Dorimo's answer

Comment: Also to the error, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68008650/node10388-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-typeerror-cannot-read-property?noredirect=1#comment120218956_68008650), fixed it with a simple addition of args.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create a function to get a mention from a message, you can use the [Message.mentions property](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions) to get the mentions, check the docs for other info about it.
This should solve your issue.

```js
const { prefix } = require("../config.json");

module.exports = {
    name: "report",
    description: "This command allows you to report a user for smurfing.",
    catefory: "misc",
    usage: "To report a player, do $report <discord name> <reason>",
    async execute(message, client) {

        const args = message.content.slice(1).trim().split(/ +/);
        const offender = message.mentions.users.first();
        // users is a collection, so we use the first method to get the first element
        // Docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection 

        if (args.length < 2 || !offender.username) {
            return message.reply('Please mention the user you want to report and specify a reason.');
        }
    
        const reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');

        message.reply(`You reported ${offender} for reason: ${reason}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, the reason client.users said undefined was that you declared Discord.client at the top of the file, even though you didn’t use that. The constructor starts with an uppercase and Discord.client is undefined

Comment: There is a problem with this, which is why a function should be used. msg.mentions.users.first()` doesn’t necessarily get the first mention in the message. It could be ordered differently, and you will need to use a mention. (This will only be a problem if you mention someone in the reason)

Comment: yeah i was worried someone would mention another user in the second message @MrMythical but to be honest this works so i will go with it

Comment: Well just remove the require discord.js part and the function can work

Comment: @MrMythical discord.js orders them as received from the API not randomly, i've used this method so many times without any problem. so i don't think there will be one

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling client in a command file if you already started a new instance of a client in your root file? try removing client from the top of the code. Hope that works

Comment: The problem is most likely not just that. It could also be in `.execute()` it is put in the wrong order

Comment: Yeah, that too.

Comment: Yes, the thing is, require('discord.js').client is undefined. The constructor starts with a capital letter. So you don't even need to require discord.js in this file!

Comment: I tried this however still get: (node:25952) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined

Comment: You took out {...} = require('discord.js')?