# (node:10388) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have been getting the above error, where I am just testing to see if I can send the offender's tag in a specific guild's channel, and the code looks pretty much like below (ignore some parts that are inconsistent. Below is the code in the cmd file.

```
const { prefix } = require("../config.json");

module.exports = {
    name: "report",
    description: "This command allows you to report a user for smurfing.",
    catefory: "misc",
    usage: "To report a player, do $report <discord name> <reason>",
    async execute(message, client) {

        const args = message.content.slice(1).trim().split(/ +/);
        const offender = message.mentions.users.first();

        if (args.length < 2 || !offender.username) {
            return message.reply('Please mention the user you want to report and specify a reason.');
        }


        const reason = args.slice(2).join(' ');

        client.channels.cache.get('xxxxx').send(offender);

        message.reply("You reported"${offender} for reason: ${reason}`);
    }
}
```

This command works without the below line completely fine.

```
client.channels.cache.get('xxxxx').send(offender);
```

but once run with this line included, I get this error.

```
(node:10388) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined
```

Below is my index file.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.prefix = prefix;
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();


const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args,client));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args,client));
    }
}

client.login(token);
```

Events:

**message.js**

```
module.exports = {
    name: "message",
    execute(message,client){
        if (!message.content.startsWith(client.prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
        const args = message.content.slice(client.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
        if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;
        try {
            client.commands.get(command).execute(message ,args, client);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
        }
    }
}
```

**ready.js**

```
module.exports = {
    name: "ready",
    once: true,
    execute(client){
        console.log("successfully logged in!");
        client.user.setActivity("VTB", {
            type: "STREAMING",
            url: "https://www.twitch.tv/monstercat"
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: can you edit the post with your message event? seems like you dont pass client from message event, and like the below answer says i dont think its a issue with the event handler itself but the event message

Comment: it seems you store the events in events folder,so edit the post with the message events files code 

You should have something like

`command.execute(message,.....something here)`

Comment: @TYPICALNINJA alright will show

Comment: oh well, you found the answer, i asked for the message event cause i needed to see what parameters you pass to your commands (you were passing `message ,args, client` but only taking `message, client` in on your command, which resulted in `client = args`, as args is the second parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue likely comes from this line:

```
(...args) => event.execute(...args, client)
```

Which means basically "take all of the parameters and pass them to `event.execute`" so you are passing an undetermined amount of parameters (depending on the event type) and the `client` is not guaranteed to be the second one as you expect.

To provide some more details, the Discord client can send multiple different types of events, and every type of event provides a different amount of parameters in the callback. In other words by writing this: `(...args) => event.execute(...args,client)` you are retrieving an unknown amount of parameters, and passing them all to the `event.execute` function, so the position of the `client` parameter could vary, and it's not necessarily the second one as you expect in the function signature: `async execute(message, client) {`

You could either retrieve only the first parameter if you don't need others, like this:

```
client.once(event.name, arg => event.execute(arg, client));
```

And if you absolutely need all of the parameters, pass the client as first so it never moves, like this:

```
client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(client, ...args));
```

Also adapt the `execute` signature:

```
async execute(client, ...args) {
```

Comment: could you elaborate a little further?

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, maybe try to mention that OP should change the order in `execute(...args, client)` to `execute(client, ...args)`. But they will need to change it in every command file too...

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros is there any other method? this would be super time consuming...

Comment: he only showed his event loader? and not his actual event of message, in the event file client will be the last argument, but in a command file it will defer, to how they pass the parameter to execute function

Comment: i tried this throughout the whole file, didn't work, ended up with
 TypeError: commands is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = {
    name: "eg",
    description: "not ready",
    category: "test",
    execute(message, args, client){
        const channel = client.channels.cache.get('853031094054944798');
            channel.send('test');
    }
}
```

it was the addition of args, before client that fixed it.

so in this example:

```
const { prefix } = require("../config.json");

module.exports = {
    name: "report",
    description: "This command allows you to report a user for smurfing.",
    catefory: "misc",
    usage: "To report a player, do $report <discord name> <reason>",
    async execute(message, args, client) {

        const args = message.content.slice(1).trim().split(/ +/);
        const offender = message.mentions.users.first();

        if (args.length < 2 || !offender.username) {
            return message.reply('Please mention the user you want to report and specify a reason.');
        }


        const reason = args.slice(2).join(' ');

        client.channels.cache.get('xxxxx').send(offender);

        message.reply("You reported"${offender} for reason: ${reason}`);
    }
}
```

It would be this.